# Style a firemonkey combobox component

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Trying to get a new style on a ComboBox in FireMonkey (XE2).
But for some odd reason I cannot get the text of a ListBoxItem to show.

What I've tried is the following.

Create a new FireMonkey HD Application.
On the form I've added a ComboBox.
Right click on the ComboBox and select 'Edit custom style'

There I've added the following components

[image: my own combobox - sub components]

while the original one consist out of the following components

[image: Original combobox - sub components]

Now it seems to me that I need the TContent object (but I can't seem to find it in the toolpallete)
How can i bind my Text object to the strings that are placed in my ComboBox?

Any pointers are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FireMonkey doesn't use a TText object to display the text. Instead it creates a copy of the list box item within the TContent (if I remember correctly).

As you've worked out you need to add a TContent to your form. The easy way to do this is to

- go back to the form,
- right click and select View as Text
- Find the TStyleBook object and add a TContent at the appropriate point (the format for this should be obvious from the rest of the file).
- No need to add any properties - defaults will be used the first time.
- Right click, View as Form.
- Go back into the style editor and edit away.

Comment: Mike your answer worked like a charm. Very nice indeed. Out of sheer curiosity do you know of any good books on this matter (FireMonkey and Components / styling) or another place where to get such information?

Comment: There are nobooks I know of, but you can try the official docwiki at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Main_Page or there's some stuff on my site at http://monkeystyler.com/guide

Comment: Ah good to know thanks a lot (I've already found lots of information on your site earlier (before asking the question above))